# "Synced" or "synched"

Tags: american-english, british-english, orthography, variants

Which is correct: *synced* or *synched*? Is one of these American and the other British spelling or are they interchangeable?

I have only ever seen *sync* used in the computing industry.

Comment: *sync,* *sanc,* *sunc*????

Comment: since the word is the short form for "synchronization" I'd suggest to analyze the word's morphology: syn- "together" (see syn-) + khronos "time" (see chrono-). so the second word's TWO LETTERS form /k/ sound ("ch" = "k") and thus - I believe the use of  "synched" would be logically correct

Comment: Relevant: [Relic as a verb: why the spelling relicing, reliced?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217329/relic-as-a-verb-why-the-spelling-relicing-reliced)

Comment: @Rossitten i have a different take. the shortened verb is *sync* not *synch*. to me, *sync* is what you're conjugating, so *synced* makes the most sense. it's also shorter, which i tend to prefer by default.

Comment: @sgroves, mks sns, m8 )

Comment: This has been an ongoing battle since the 70s, at least.  The terms are mostly used in computer and electronics contexts, where forming abbreviations is a common (and necessary) activity.  Many, including myself, prefer "sync", in large part because an annoying number of people tend to pronounce "synch" as "cinch".  But both are fairly common.

Comment: What @HotLicks said.

Comment: How about `sync'd`?

Comment: Synch is awful. I just go with my gut on this one. Sync or Synced is crisp, clear and concise. On the other hand, synch is the Grinch who stole Christmas; Bad! Really bad! Ugh! Disgusting!!! Long live the Sync!

Comment: Both are in the dictionary, however, between sync and synch, I prefer sync, because the trailing 'c' feels better with the hard-k sound.  Synch always feels like it is a 'ch' sound not a 'k' sound, and some people pronounce it "cinch."
Between synced and synched I don't like either.  synced looks like it would be pronounced "sin-sd" and synched looks like "cinched" (what you do with a belt.)  
I tend to write it sync-ed, but that's just me.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

The [Corpus of Contemporary American English](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/) has 30 incidences of *synced* and 14 of *synched*. Over half of the incidences of *synced* are from the magazine *PC World*, though. *Synced* does appear to be most commonly used in computing contexts.

Comment: There is a Unix command called *sync*, from section 8 of the manual (system administration).  That may have influenced it.  I guess you could write that you'd *sync* (8)ed the disks, but certainly *synched* looked better than the hypothetical (and largely unattested) *syncked*.

Answer (score 26):

[American English](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=synced,synched&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=5&smoothing=3): 
[image: American English]

[British English](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=synced,synched&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3):
[image: British English]

*Synched* is more popular than *synced* for both American and British English, but the gap is closer in British English.

I've seen both used in the computer industry. The common and my preferred way of abbreviating *synchronous* is *sync*, rather than *synch*, partly because it makes more sense to pronounce it as *sink* than *sinch* and the shorter abbreviation is simpler and clearer. Also to avoid any confusion with the slang word *cinch* (pronounced *sinch*).

For similar reasons and consistency, I'd recommend  *synced* over  *synched* and *async* over *asynch*.

You'll also save ink and disk space.

Comment: Don't both of these graphs show the popularity of *synched*, not *synced*?

Comment: It appears that way to me as well. @Hugo should clarify or correct. -1 until then.

Comment: Don't know why his graph stopped at the year 2000, because right after that, _synced_ overtook _synched_. http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=synced%2Csynched&year_start=1960&year_end=2010&corpus=5&smoothing=3&share=

Comment: Another data point might be https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=synced,synched

Answer (score 16):

***Merriam-Webster on 'sync' versus 'synch'***

In the United States, many publications (including *PC World*, which nohat specifically mentions in his answer) use *Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary* as their default guide to spelling words, and the historical preference of Merriam-Webster for *sync* over *synch* goes back very far—certainly to an era before personal computers.

The first time *sync/synch* shows up in the *Collegiate Dictionary* series in in the *Sixth Edition* (1949). Here is the relevant entry:

> **sync**, *n.* & *v.* Also **synch**. *Motion Pictures & Television*. Short for SYNCHRONIZATION, SYNCHRONIZE.

This brief entry tells us that from 1949, when *sync/synch* first became common enough to merit (in the eyes of Merriam-Webster's lexicographers) an entry in the *Collegiate Dictionary* series, the publisher viewed *sync* as the more common spelling of the word. The entry also tells us that the original preference for *sync* probably arose in the film and television industry, a field where the fact that the *ch* in *synchronize* can be traced to the chi (χ) in *chronos* (χρονος) was probably not of widespread interest or concern.

The *Seventh Collegiate* (1963) dispenses with the *-ch* spelling altogether:

> **<sup>1</sup>sync** *n* **:** SYNCHRONIZATION, SYNCHRONISM —**sync** *adj*
>
> **<sup>2</sup>sync** *vb* **synced syncing :** SYNCHRONIZE

The spelling *synch* makes a comeback in the *Eighth Collegiate* (1973):

> **<sup>1</sup>sync** *also* **synch** *n* **:** SYNCHRONIZATION, SYNCHRONISM —**sync** *adj*
>
> **<sup>2</sup>sync** *also* **synch** *vt* **synced** *also* **synched** **syncing** *also* **synching :** SYNCHRONIZE

The *Ninth* (1983), *Tenth* (1993), and *Eleventh* (2003) *Collegiates* have retained the skeleton of the entries from the *Eighth Collegiate*, but they have added a couple of examples of *sync* as a noun, and they report that *sync* as a noun dates to 1929 and *sync* as a verb to 1945.

As this chronology demonstrates, for the past 57 years, *Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary* has always expressed a preference for *sync* over *synch* as the primary spelling of this truncated word—and for the period 1963–1972, it didn't include *synch* as even a variant spelling.

---

***Ngram charts of 'sync' versus 'synch' and 'synced' versus 'synched'***

In his answer, Hugo provides Ngram charts of relative frequency of use of *synced* and *synched* in American English and in British English for the period 1960–2000. These are interesting charts, but they don't reflect a rather significant difference in frequency of use between *sync* and *synch*.  Here is the chart I got for *sync* (blue line) versus *synch* (red line) for the period 1900–2008, with no year-to-year smoothing and no distinction between British English and U.S. English sources:

[image]

And here is the corresponding Ngram chart for *synced* (blue line) versus *synched* for the same period with the same conditions:

[image]

The rather startling thing here is the difference between the results for *sync/synch* (where sync has a huge advantage in frequency of usage over *synch*) and *synced/synched* (where between 1989 and 2005 *synched* was the more common form).

On this record it appears that people are far more likely to choose *sync* over *synch* than to choose *synced* over *synched*. Nevertheless, in the most recent years for which Ngram offers graph data (2006–2008), *synced* appears to have moved ahead of *synched* in overall frequency, too.

---

***Conclusion***

Returning briefly to nohat's remarks about *PC World* magazine, I observe that *PC World* began publication in 1983, well into the era of Merriam-Webster's express preference for *sync* (and *synced*) over *synch* (and *synched*). When I started working at *PC World* in 1995, I tried to use the spelling *synch*—because of the ancient Greek single letter (χ) for *ch*, obviously—and I was told that house style was *sync*, *synced*, *syncing* because Merriam-Webster recommended it. Case closed. Under the circumstances, it's surprising that *synched* has done as well as it has against *synced*, especially when you consider how thoroughly *sync* has dominated *synch* during the same period.

Comment: Kind of a short answer for you.  Usually you throw in everything but the kitchen synch.

Comment: @HotLicks: Yeah, but answering this one was a cinc.

Comment: I posit that _synx_ is a more logical derivative. As a bonus: 'x' is way cooler than 'c'.

Answer (score 12):

The spelling "synch" is a variant of "sync", and "sync" (synced) is the one mostly used.

Both are the informal short form of *synchronize* (as in *synchronization*).

Comment: as a verb, it’s short for *synchronize*

Answer (score 6):

I have several computer-savvy friends, and they use the word a lot.  I have only ever seen *synced*.

Looking at the Ngram of "synced" vs. "synched", I see that since the widespread use of computers, "synched" is becoming more popular.  However, the spellchecker on this site does not recognize "synched", and Dictionary.com does not help with the past tense form of "sync".  So make of that what you will.

http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/chart?content=synced%2Csynched%2Csyncked&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3

Answer (score 5):

In the Roman Alphabet, the voiceless velar fricative is represented by the ch digraph. However, most words containing a voiceless velar fricative in borrowee language have the voiceless velar fricative coverted into a voiceless velar plosive, due to English-speakers' traditional inability to voice the appropriate pronunciation.

Thus, in the english language,because the H in Synchronise no longer serves a purpose at all (the ch digraph being converted into a sound that can be represented solely by C), Sync would be more correct that Synch would if you're following the rules established in the English language.

http://languagelover.blogspot.com/2009/09/sync-or-synch.html

Answer (score 4):

The OED records the word as a noun and gives both spellings.

Comment: I presume that's for "sync"/"synch". What about "synced"/"synched"?

Comment: @Hugo: There is no separate entry for 'sync/synch' as a verb. However, the noun entry includes these two citations: 'If they . . . are synced with a clock and thus with each other' and 'They wanted it synched to within one frame.' The entry also says that 'sink' is another form of the word.

Answer (score 2):

Both are questionable abbreviations of "synchronized".

If one insists on the "sync" neologism, then "synced" looks more reasonable to me.

Comment: Why are they "questionable"?

Comment: Because they are not in the dictionary.

Comment: Which dictionary is "the" dictionary? Because they are in _some_ dictionaries.

Comment: There was the expression "in sync" even before computers got involved.

Comment: @PavelRadzivilovsky dictionaries attempt to describe language. they don't define it.

Answer (score 2):

"Synced" is a little confusing for the reader since it could be pronounced like "since", thus the "synched" spelling is probably to make it more readable.

Comment: Of course, "synched" can easily be pronounced as "cinched" by mistake.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a longtime American IT executive, not a linguist, but I see both variations in IT:

- "sync" is very common, e.g., in the name of the widespread utility "rsync" (of Australian origin); "synch" is less common but still frequently seen
- "synched" is more common than "synced"
- "synching" is uncommon; "syncing" is uncommon, too, especially recently

Answer (score 1):

The grammar rule which has applied to words ending with the letter C states the addition of the K, as in *picnicked*, *shellacked*, *tarmacked*, *mimicked*, *zincked*, etc. While we're talking about the abbreviations of *synchronize* which allow *sync* or *synch*, the version we choose determines what is proper. Ultimately, this is a decision between *synched* (which I would discourage, but that's just my opinion) or *syncked*, never *synced*.

Comment: -1. This "rule" doesn't match usage even a little for _sync[h]_, and I'm frankly dubious about several of your other examples.

Comment: The exception proves the rule....

Comment: How about *synchked*? Or *synckhed*?

Answer (score 1):

The word you are actually looking for is "synchronised" (BE) or "synchronized" (AE)

"Synced" is an incorrect extension of the abbreviation "sync" which is equal to "synch" (it has just been abbreviated one letter more).

Comment: Not sure *incorrect* if a fair description. Perhaps *new* or *recently evolved*?