# What is the past tense of "sync"?

Tags: verbs, past-tense

I've always believed the past tense of *sync* ("I sync my phone with my computer") to be *synced* ("I synced my phone with my computer yesterday").  [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/681/which-is-correct-synced-or-synched) would seem to suggest either *synced* or *synched*.  I have a friend who insists the past tense is *sunk*.  I'd appreciate if you could make this clear for me.

Comment: It's not sunk. Sunk is the past tense of sink which is spelt differently to sync.

Comment: @Ambo100 That's what I thought; perhaps my friend is just confused, or perhaps he spells "sunk" differently for "sync" (I have only heard him say it out loud).

Comment: It's a a matter of working out if it's synced or synched, In that case I think you'll find the answer [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/681/which-is-correct-synced-or-synched)

Comment: @Ambo100: And it doesn't even matter if the word is spelled differently, e.g. *lie* (recline) -> *lay* but *lie* (speak untruths) -> *lied*. Another: *ring* (bell sound) -> *rang* but *ring* (circle) -> *ringed*. Homophony doesn't entail monomorphy.

Comment: I was always intrigued by _set_ (cement) -> _set_ but _set_ (pupils) -> _setted_, and by _bid_ (farewell) -> _bade_ but _bid_ (at auction) -> _bid_ (UK) or, I believe, _bidded_ (US). I also find fascinating that we usually seem to use the past tense _sped_ in the UK (he _sped_ up the motorway) except in the multi-word-verb expression _speed up_ (when he realised how late he was, he _speeded up_).

Comment: It's definitely "synch'd" but I usually *say* "sank" ("sunk" is just weird).  But everytime I go to write it, I realize that "sank" is wrong, and am reminded that it's "synch'd" (the apostrophe is for the missing letters).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The past tense is "synced". "Sunk" is the past tense of "sink" which sounds the same but is a completely different word. "Synced" appears to have made its way into dictionaries:

- [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synced)
- [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sync)
- [TheFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/synced)
- [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/synced?r=66)
- and I am sure many others

> Edit: As others have pointed out, "synch" and "synched" are acceptable variants.

Comment: Perhaps I'm the only one in the world, but I've also used *sync'd* in the past, which is what I (computer geek) tend to do to put an odd computerish word in the past tense. Now that I know it's "official" to say "synced", I'll do so.

Comment: @Wayne: I _have_ seen "sync'd" but the apostrophe was likely dropped when the non-tech world began using the word.

Comment: perhaps sync'd was short for synchronized, but now that sync is an accepted word, it has its own past tense form?

Comment: @Wayne I have also used and seen *sync'd*, but recently that's been trending toward *synched*.  I still know plenty of people who insist on using *sunk* too.

Comment: What about the pronunciation? Synced and syncing both look like they should be pronounced /sɪnst/ and /sɪnsɪŋ/, but it seems that the only acceptable pronunciation is /sɪnkt/ and /sɪnkɪŋ/. Shouldn't we add a K between C and E/I to avoid that? Or is it just me with my Romance Language background trying to make sense of something that is not supposed to be regular?

Comment: @marcus: The correct pronunciation is similar to "sinked". Trying to update the pronunciation or spelling so that they match sounds similar to [Hypercorrection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypercorrection). This is just another word in English that needs to be remembered as an exception. For what it is worth, this is probably one of the reasons the word was originally spelled *sync'd* -- it forced the reader to register the word as a variant of *sync* which itself derived from *synchronize*.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just expected that newer words would avoid an inconsistency like that (it is not hypercorrection when the correct form is not established yet :-) — but it seems it *is* established now as synced...)

Comment: @Wayne No. You're not alone.

Answer (score 6):

The past tense of **to sync**, which is *to synchronise*, is **synced**:

> Example taken from the NOAD: *The flash needs to be synced to your camera.*

Since the verb can also be spelt as **to synch**, the related past tense can also be **synched**.

Answer (score 3):

The past tense of *sync* is *synced*, while the past tense of *synch* (which is the alternative to *sync*) is *synched*.
*Sync* is a short for *synchronize*; I would rather avoid the short version, and say *synchronized* when you need the past tense.

Comment: "Sync" is a word. You can use it without fear along with "synced" and "syncing".

Comment: @MrHen I know it's a word, but if I have to debate with somebody else if the past tense is _sunk_ or _synced_, I prefer using _synchronized_.

Answer (score 2):

It is most certainly not "sunk." This having been said, there's probably no lasting harm in your friend's colloquial use of the word, unless he's representing you or your company in any official capacity. In which case, I'd consider "sunk" sunk.

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer to use *sync'd* or *synched*, as I believe that if it is spelt *synced* then it would be pronounced *sinst*.

Comment: This is the correct rationale for the currently accepted past tense forms of *sync'd* and *synched*.

Comment: I dislike "synced".  It is well established that the verb "to picnic" adds a "k" in its "-ing" and "-ed" forms.  Since the verb "to sync" is derived from "synchronized", an "h" would be more appropriate than a "k", but I think the same principle should apply.