# Abbreviation of "(a)synchronous"

Tags: abbreviations

How should one go about abbreviating *(a)synchronous*? Is the most correct form *(a)sync.* or *(a)synch.*?

Comment: Hello User. In my opinion this is easily answerable looking at the dictionary. I couldn't find "async", but "sync" is in every dictionary; Same goes for "synch" more or less, so I suppose it's up to you about which one to use.

Comment: See related [past tense of synchronize](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/25725/what-is-the-past-tense-of-sync) and [which is correct synced or synched](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/681/which-is-correct-synced-or-synched).

Comment: Both abbreviated forms are used.  It kinda depends on which computer or computer language you worked with first.

Answer (score 3):

The common and my preferred way of abbreviating *synchronous* is *sync*, rather than *synch*, partly because it makes more sense to pronounce it as *sink* than *sinch* and the shorter abbreviation is simpler and clearer. Also to avoid any confusion with the slang word *cinch* (pronounced like *sinch*).

For similar reasons and consistency, I'd recommend *async* over *asynch*.

Comment: As a bonus, it's also one letter shorter!

Comment: Yes! Save time, ink and disk space!

Comment: Why do you say "cinch" is slang?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai It's an informal term for something that's easy to do.

Comment: @Hugo Oh, I see. It also has non-slang use, a "cinch" sack, which is what I was thinking of.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai Is *cinch* as in sack pronounced "kinch" rather than "sinch"?

Comment: @Hugo No, that's why I didn't get why you thought it was slang. Is "cinch sack." Is it not common where you're from?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai No. I know that verb *cinch*, but I'd probably call those *drawstring bags*.

Comment: @Hugo Interesting. No idea it was regional

Answer (score 1):

[image: Ngram for "sync" versus "synch", 1920-2000]

The graph for *async* versus *asynch* is similar. From this I would say that *sync* and *async* are preferred.

Comment: The image is broken, please could you fix it?