# "Lip-sync" or "Lip-synch"?

Tags: etymology, orthography, morphology, word-formation, derivational-morphology

What is the correct spelling of the expression "lip sync[h]," which refers to miming singing over a recording--usually in a public performance and with the intention to mislead?

Google has approximately 13,700,000 results for "lip-sync," and only ~465,000 for "lip synch" (presumably, it ignores the hyphens). It also suggests "lip sync" as a correction for "lip synch." However, [Webster's](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lip%E2%80%93sync), [Cambridge](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/lip-synch), and [Macmillan](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/lip-synch) give "lip synch" as a headword, and list "lip sync" as a variant or not at all.

What, then, is truly the preferred spelling according to (American-) English convention? I am interested in an answer that makes a compelling argument for one choice or another--informed by knowledge and example of the morphological norms of English, and particularly the rules of clipping--rather than argue that both are acceptable.

Related, but not a duplicate (as it does not treat the fixed phrase with "lip-," but instead other uses of "synch"): ["Synced" or "synched"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/681/synced-or-synched)

Comment: Try using Ngram: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lip+sync%2Clip+synch%2Clip-sync%2Clip-synch&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clip%20sync%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clip%20synch%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clip%20-%20sync%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clip%20-%20synch%3B%2Cc0 .  Prior to 1995 "sync" was the clear winner, but lately there is disturbance in the force.  (However, it's not unusual for recent numbers to be "odd", perhaps due to the lag in entering documents into the database.)

Comment: There is no real reason to expect that having a "lip-" prefix would change folks' preference for the spelling of "sync", and that spelling has been preferred by techies over "synch" for decades.

Comment: @HotLicks It's not unimaginable one group -- musicians -- spelled it one way, and another -- programmers -- independently developed a different standard. Unlikely, but I'd believe it.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai - Yeah, my recollection is that, circa 1975, there was a "battle" of sorts between the two spellings.  While "sync" was probably always the most popular, there were those in the techie community arguing for "synch", and different sub-disciplines would adopt different spellings.  Likely the same was true outside the techie community.  (And much the same holds for "disk" and "disc",though that battle is still going on.)

Comment: Yeah, "disc" and "disk"! That's the example I was trying to come up with.

Answer (score 3):

My Merriam-Webster Unabridged lists:

- The noun form of *sync* (*the sound track is out of sync with the actors' lips*)
- The verb form of *sync* (*timecode is a great aid for syncing*)
- The adjective form of *sync* ("relating to or having to do with synchronization")
- The abbreviation *sync* (which it lists without comment)
- The noun *lip sync* (the primary definition being "lip synchronization")
- The adjective *lip-sync* ("of, relating to, or produced by lip synchronization or lip sync")
- The verb *lip-synch*, which **does** list *lip-sync* as an alternative form ("to pretend to sing or say (something) in synchronization with recorded sound")

Of the forms of *sync* listed, **only** the noun form lists *synch* as an alternative form.

Given the preponderance of the spelling *sync* in their definitions, I find it curious that M-W list *lip-synch* as the headword of the verb form.

Their own definitions seem to come down firmly on the side of *lip-sync*.