# "Synced" or "Synchronized"?

Tags: word-choice

I could not add to [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/681/synced-or-synched/159702#159702) question but I would like to know if it is still relevant to use *synchronized* in computing context or is it considered too formal and it is preferred to use *synched/synced* instead?

Comment: Personally I like *sunc* but I can't get it to catch on (apparently neither can Peter Shor, going by the linked question) . *Sync**h**ed* looks old-fashioned, but computing is a huge field and a user manual is very different to an academic paper in terms of formality. This isn't quite the same question, though the answers may overlap.

Comment: I normally avoid the issue by using *in sync*.

Comment: To what extend do you consider English *in a computing context* to be different from standard English?  Isn't this just a matter of personal opinion?  Or are there special rules that apply to the dialect of technical writers?  I think the question is either more or less answerable depending on one's assumptions.

Comment: That's a tough one @Rob_Ster but I don't think that usually you would refer to something as formally as to say "that needs to be synchronized" or "the server is synchronized", probably more so following the path of what @ Chris H was saying to a writing versus speaking? I know that the _in sync_ of @ Mick could spare us some trouble but what about a "Proceed synchronization" button? That on which you click before you see the "we are now working on your request" sort. Should it become something like "Sync!" and the reply? "You are now in sync"/Synced/Synchronized? Is it ok to use either form?

Comment: Sorry and I don't understand why anyone graced that with an Answer here.

If you're making a difference between English and some 'computing context' it's entirely up to you whether this or that is too formal and whether it's preferred to use synched/synced instead…

Comment: This is wordchoice @RobbieGoodwin, I want to know which word is preferable if it feels natural to use one over the other. The replies I got so far lead us to think it is a tad irrelative, which is what I asked. Maybe I did digress a bit on the previous comment and that's what you're referring to?

Comment: Really? If this is *wordchoice* then it has no place in English Language Users… read the forum *Tour* and *Help* at the bottom of your page.

That said, when you can make your own argument for doing so it might be appropriate to use synched/synced. Until then, why not stick with the formal standard?

Comment: I did take the tour, it talks about having trouble choosing one word over the other. This is the case. Thanks.

Comment: Define "*computing context*". Know your audience. Respect whatever style guide you're using. If you're not using a style guide then it's up to you. Primarily opinion-based.

Comment: I use 'synched' in my reports - 'I synched my voice recorder to the CCTV image'.

Answer (score 1):

I would use 'synchronize' when referring to just two items that needed to 'sync up', but then use 'sync' when referring to the entire system, platform, or a group of programs which will be synced all at once.

Comment: Why? (Hint: improve your answer)